# Spring Boot -Dspring.config.location vs --spring.config.location

Tags: spring-boot

What's difference between -Dspring.config.location and --spring.config.location for running Spring Boot in command line?

I saw more than one tutorials and stackoverflow answers running command in this way:

```
java -jar test.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:test/application.properties
```

However, no matter how I tried, I failed to load the properties file whereas another way succeeded:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=classpath:test/application.properties test.jar
```

I am confused with these two settings.

My project is using:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
</plugin>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The way I tested:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Test implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Test.class);  
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(context.getId());
    }

}
```

The first way output is "application". The second way can read my value from  my properties file. There are no any errors for both.

Thanks.

Comment: The first one, with the `--spring.config.location` you are passing the config to the Spring boot, the one with the `-D` you are passing the arguments to the JVM. Both ways should work, any errors messages you can provide?

Comment: I updated my post to reply your question.